# How to insert "\\" chars inside a PDF text ? I'm writing the file manually

Tags: pdf

I'm writing PDF files by hand...

I put some words with some codes inside a text file. When I change the file extension to ".pdf" we can see a PDF file.

The problem is about backslashes in a text...

The content of my file includes something like :

```
\\127.0.0.1\
```

but when I open the .pdf file generated, I see my text without a backslash:

```
\127.0.0.1\
```

My code:

```
    %PDF-1.2 
    %ÓÓÓÓ
    1 0 obj
    <<
    /Creator  (Dinesh Asanka PSOPDF)
    /Producer (VB to PDF dineshasanka@hotmail.com)
    /Title (VBTOPDF)
    >>
    endobj
    4 0 obj
    <<
    /Type /Font
    /Subtype /Type1
    /Name /F1
    /Encoding 5 0 R
    /BaseFont /Courier
    >>
    endobj
    5 0 obj
    <<
    /Type /Encoding
    /BaseEncoding /WinAnsiEncoding
    >>
    endobj
    6 0 obj
    <<
    /Font << /F1 4 0 R   >>  /ProcSet [ /PDF  /Text ]
    >>
    endobj
    7 0 obj
    <<
    /Type /Page
    /Parent 3 0 R
    /Resources 6 0 R
    /Contents 8 0 R
    >>
    endobj
    8 0 obj
    <<
    /Length 9 0 R
    >>
    stream
    BT
    /F1 10 Tf
    1 0 0 1 1 780 Tm
    12 TL
    T* (                                          Impressoras de NF) Tj
    T* (                                                                                      Loja Logada: 1) Tj
    T* (                                                                                    Data: 03/03/2015) Tj
    T* (                                                                                      Versao: 4.0.2u) Tj
    T* (------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------) Tj
    T* (            IP Nome              Localização Store Serie ) Tj
    T* (               Impressora                               ) Tj
    T* (------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------) Tj
    0.392 0.392 0.392 rg
    T* ( 192.168.17.22 192.168.17.22\pdf PDF            1     1 ) Tj
    0.000 0.000 0.000 rg
    T* (  192.168.17.6 \\Directory\EPSONNF  CPD            1     0 ) Tj
    0.392 0.392 0.392 rg
    T* (          ) Tj
    ET
    endstream
    endobj
    9 0 obj
    315
    endobj
    2 0 obj
    <<
    /Type /Catalog
    /Pages 3 0 R
    /PageLayout /OneColumn
    >>
    endobj
    3 0 obj
    <<
    /Type /Pages
    /Count 1
    /MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]
    /Kids [ 7 0 R ]
    >>
    endobj
    xref
    010
    0000000000 65535 f
    0000000017 00000 n
    0000000880 00000 n
    0000000959 00000 n
    0000000144 00000 n
    0000000247 00000 n
    0000000321 00000 n
    0000000396 00000 n
    0000000484 00000 n
    0000000858 00000 n
    trailer
    <<
    /Size 10
    /Root 2 0 R
    /Info 1 0 R
    >>
    startxref
    1052
    %%EOF
```

How can I print my address with two backslashes?

Comment: The back slash is an escape character in strings like that. You have to replace each of your back slashes by two of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"The problem is about backslashes in a text..."*

That's not the only problem with your file. Look also at the very bottom of my answer. See for example how this word from your PDF source code renders:

```
Localização
```

As soon as your text needs non-ASCII characters, you cannot use any more the simple

```
(some string) Tj
```

approach any more. You have to switch (at least for the text parts using non-ASCII) of text/string coding.

You have two options.

### 1. Either use the `<aa bb cc...>` (hex) method

Example for `some string`:

```
<73 6f 6d 65 20 73 74 72 69 6e 67>Tj
```

Note, that you can use whitespace freely inside the `<....>` hex part, like this:

```
<73  6f6d65 2073  74 72 69 6e67>Tj
```

and it will not make any difference to the rendered text.

However, this will not cover ***all*** the characters which are available in your used `/WinAnsiEncoding`.

### 2. Or use the `(\NNN\MMM\...)` (octal) method

Same example, `some string`:

```
(\163\157\155\145\040\163\164\162\151\156\147) Tj
```

You can mix octal encoding of characters within the same `(...)` string:

```
(s\157\155\145 \163\164\162ing) Tj
```

Now you also can guess, why a literal `\` does not work in strings: because it serves as the start mark for any octal encoded character.

### 3. Now for your `\` characters

As a Hex value the `\` character is presented by `5c`.

As an octal value (for `/WinAnsiEncoding`) it is `\134`.

So you could write your `\\Directory\EPSONNF` string as

```
 (\134\134Directory\134EPSONNF) Tj
```

or

```
 <5c5c>Tj (Directory\134EPSONNF) Tj
```

(You cannot mix a `<..> Tj` method inside the `(...) Tj` method...)

### 4. Last, your `Localização` string

Try it with this:

```
(Localiza\347\343o) Tj
```

### 5. More problems with your PDF

Finally, your PDF has some more problems:

1. The value given for `startxref` is incorrect.
2. The line length in your `xref` entries must be exactly 20 characters (including the EOL characte). If you use a single-byte EOL, you have to add a trailing space character (after the `f` and `n` characters).
3. The line after `xref` must read `0 10`, not `010`.
4. The values for the `xref` lines are wrong per se. (Not even a single one is correct.)

Comment: *As soon as your text needs non-ASCII characters, you cannot use any more the simple `(some string) Tj`* - well, as long as the OP takes care to properly encode that `(some string) Tj`, there are many characters beyond ASCII he can put into it, especially considering he chose **WinAnsiEncoding** for his font there.

Answer (score 3):

*In addition to @Kurt's answer:*

The reverse solidus `\` not only *serves as the start mark for any octal encoded character*. Instead it can be used for different purposes:

> ```
> Sequence Meaning
> \n       LINE FEED (0Ah) (LF)
> \r       CARRIAGE RETURN (0Dh) (CR)
> \t       HORIZONTAL TAB (09h) (HT)
> \b       BACKSPACE (08h) (BS)
> \f       FORM FEED (FF)
> \(       LEFT PARENTHESIS (28h)
> \)       RIGHT PARENTHESIS (29h)
> \\       REVERSE SOLIDUS (5Ch) (Backslash)
> \ddd     Character code ddd (octal)
> ```
>
> *(Table 3 – Escape sequences in literal strings, [PDF spec](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

Thus, you can get your desired output like this, too:

```
0.392 0.392 0.392 rg
T* ( 192.168.17.22 192.168.17.22\\pdf PDF            1     1 ) Tj
0.000 0.000 0.000 rg
T* (  192.168.17.6 \\\\Directory\\EPSONNF  CPD            1     0 ) Tj
0.392 0.392 0.392 rg
T* (          ) Tj
```

PS: Even though CR, LF, etc are mentioned in that table, *they cannot be used to break lines in the text **drawn*** with such text drawing operations.